# How to replace a missing value with a previous value in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to replace missing value with previous one  but unable to do that just want explanation how i can overwrite previous value

```
data test; 
 input name $ num;
datalines;
 aa 11
 .  12 
 .  13 
 .  14 
 bb 90 
 .  83 
 .  21 
 cc 21 
 .  21 
 dd 24 
 ee 89 
 ff 89 
 .  87 
 .  22 
; 
run;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is called Last Observation Carry Forward (LOCF).  One way to do it in SAS is with the RETAIN statement.

```
data test; 
 input name $ num;
datalines;
 aa 11
 .  12 
 .  13 
 .  14 
 bb 90 
 .  83 
 .  21 
 cc 21 
 .  21 
 dd 24 
 ee 89 
 ff 89 
 .  87 
 .  22 
; 
run;

data want ;
  set test (rename=(name=_name)) ;
  length name $8 ;
  retain name ;
  if not missing (_name) then name=_name ;
  drop _: ;
run ;

proc print ;
run ;
```